# Run rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin framework, I followed the  ActiveAdmin's getting started and in the last step `rails generate active_admin:resource [MyModelName]` I write this: `rails generate active_admin:resource User` then I tried to see the results in the browser so I run the server `rails s` and then I get this problem:

```
 edu@edu-ThinkPad-Edge:~/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo$ rails server
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
 => Call with -d to detach
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/app/admin/users.rb:1:in `<top
 (required)>': uninitialized constant User (NameError)  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in
 `block in load!'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in
 `each'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in
 `load!'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:197:in
 `routes'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin.rb:83:in
 `routes'   from
 /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in
 <top (required)>'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in
 `instance_exec'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in
 `eval_block'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in
 `draw'     from
 /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top
 (required)>'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in
 `block in load_paths'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in
 `each'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in
 `load_paths'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in
 `reload!'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in
 `reload!'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in
 `block in attach!'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
 `_run__246534365__prepare__874865436__callbacks'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
 `__run_callback'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
 `_run_prepare_callbacks'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
 `run_callbacks'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in
 `prepare!'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in
 `prepare!'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in
 `block in <module:Finisher>'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
 `method_missing'   from
 /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config/environment.rb:5:in
 `<top (required)>'     from
 /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config.ru:3:in `block in
 <main>'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
 `instance_eval'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
 `initialize'   from /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config.ru:in
 `new'  from /home/edu/Desktop/rails_proyects/fulbo/config.ru:in
 `<main>'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
 `eval'     from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
 `parse_file'   from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in
 `app'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in
 `wrapped_app'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in
 `start'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in
 `block in <top (required)>'    from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
 `tap'  from
 /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@fulbo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
 `<top (required)>'     from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
 script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

someone knows how to fix it or what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure, you did `bundle exec rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: I did that and I get this : rake aborted! uninitialized constant User

Comment: Is this IP/port you're trying to run the server on correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is - ActiveAdmin is trying to generate resource on `users`, but model for `users` doesn't exist. Therefore, you will have to create a model `User` before you generate active_admin resource on User.

Do it as follows:

```
rm app/admin/users.rb
rails generate model User username: string email: string
bundle exec rake db:migrate
#this should be successful
rails generate active_admin:resource User
rails server
```

Let me know, if it helps you out. Comment with the errors you encounter.

Good luck

Comment: thank for your help!
the problem was I had not an User model in my project  :P.